# How to format msmtp terminal command string for delphi or lazarus?

Tags: string, delphi, terminal, string-formatting, lazarus

I am testing MSMTP terminal command for sending emails.

```
$ echo -e "Subject: Testing msmtp \nHello, this is msmtp." | msmtp myemail@gmail.com
```

This terminal command works flawlessly just as I expect when I actually run this command within a console or terminal, but when I run the same or EXACT command within my Delphi or Lazarus program, it fails to run or run unexpectedly.

Here is the freepascal code:

```
...
fpsystem('echo -e "Subject: Testing msmtp \nHello, this is msmtp." | msmtp myemail@gmail.com');
...
```

or

```
...
Process1.CommandLine := 'echo -e "Subject: Testing msmtp \nHello, this is msmtp." | msmtp myemail@gmail.com';
Process1.execute;
...
```

Both of these codes do send emails and body of the message included, but there is no subject line, even though it is included in the terminal command. I realize that this is due to string formatting within my program. How do you format this terminal command for delphi or Lazarus? So, that it executes the same way as it does from within a terminal or console. I tried escaping double quotation marks with `\"` but didn't work.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to an external process like msmtp at all, instead of just using an SMTP library directly in your code?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because I tried it already and it wouldn't login to send email.

Comment: The SMTP protocol works just fine when used in application code.  If you were using an SMTP library and couldn't get it to login, then you likely just weren't using it correctly, or it was outdated with modern authentication practices. There are tons of libraries to pick from, if one doesn't work, try another.

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm, I just found LNET installed in my compiler and tried it. It worked... I thought it wouldn't. This works great, because I can also send attachment... Cool... :) thanks... but I still think this question should be answered with a working code. It can also be applied in other areas of string operation or manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In general test your lines with a command processor, e.g. do sh -c   resp. cmd.exe  /C work?  Also, less quoting might be required, since TProcess will do quoting for you if you add parameters one by one.

I don't know why the fpsystem doesn't work, maybe wrong shell?

The TProcess case is simple, there is no commandprocessor invoked by TProcess, it calls the create process API directly.

For the Windows case, execute the shell (cmd.exe) and add two parameters (arguments.add(), one "/C" and the other the complete commandline, both without the outer quotes.

The commandline property is deprecated, I recommend against using it, specially in more complicated cases like this.

Also, the Windows echo command doesn't seem to know a -e parameter, which is why I suggest you test your commandlines first (the \n in commandline also seems a *nixism)